# How do I select 'open' on a file download popup using python?

Tags: python, hyperlink, popup

I have a link say, "http://www.prt-inc.com/forecast.csv"
I use this code to open the link

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://www.prt-inc.com/forecast.csv')
```

Now this link opens a 'File Download' popup. The popup has 'open' 'save' 'cancel' on it.

I would like to write code that would 'click' on open or save and work with the file. But also I wouldn't want the link to physically open up in a browswer, just do it all in the background if possible. So I'm not sure if using 'webbrowser' is the proper thing to use.
I am a beginner in python and not sure at all where to start or if there is different libraries to use to do this type of thing.
If I could get some hints or tips, or get pointed in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: You should send an HTTP request directly, without using a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with the file I think you'd be better off using the [urllib2 library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com").read()
```

This is assuming you have python 2.x. Python 3.x has some slight [variations](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib.request#examples)